# Restore Windows 7 bootloader after Windows 8 install

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, bootloader

I have installed Windows 8 onto a partition after Windows 7, and when I turn my PC on, Windows 8 basically loads completely, and then I get the option to choose my OS. If I select Windows 8, I go straight to the lock screen, if I select Windows 7, my computer completely restarts and then boots into 7.

I want to use the Windows 7 installation DVD to restore the Windows 7 bootloader using the [method described by the How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) but I am worried that if I do this, Windows 8 won't boot.

Can anybody advise on whether or not this will work, and if not how can I go back to selecting the OS right after the BIOS loads?

Comment: JMK: Do you have a real issue with the current bootloader, or you just don't like the behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 requires the Windows 8 bootloader to boot.  It's part of the fast boot process.

There are some theoretical solutions, such as loading grub or system commander to boot either Windows 8 or Windows 7 bootloaders, but there's a lot of work involved there and i'm unsure of whether they work with EFI and GPT setups.  Why don't you just set Windows 7 as the default OS and let it boot automatically.  It may take a bit longer, but you won't have to do anything to make it boot 7.

You set 7 as the default in the System Properties -> Advanced Tab -> Startup and Recovery

Answer (score 2):

Use EasyBCD. It installs the Windows 7 bootloader. But you'll lose Fast Startup. Rest everything will be fine. Done it on a friend's PC. No problems till now. However, if yours is UEFI boot, then I'm not too sure. This works on a BIOS

Answer (score -1):

Windows 8 bootloader can load Windows 7, you just need to add the menu for it.

I restored load to Vista installed on another partition using `bcdedit` command without using 3rd party tools.

### Listing Current Settings

Start Command Prompt with Administrative privileges.

If run `bcdedit` without parameters it will list your current settings:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
...

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 8
...
```

### Creating a Backup

*Making a backup is **always** a good thing:*

```
bcdedit /export C:\BCD-Backup
```

If something goes wrong, you would be able to recover with

```
bcdedit /import C:\BCD-Backup /clean
```

### Adding Entry for Windows 7

So now we'll add another entry.

1. Copy the current settings to a new record:

   ```
   bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows 7"
   Entry copied successfully to {GUID}.
   ```

   Here `{GUID}` is a place holder for the identifier of the new entry,
   it consists of numbers and characters. You will copy this GUID and *use it* in place of `{GUID}` placeholder in the step 2.
2. Modify the copied entry to boot from drive D:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {GUID} device partition=D:
   bcdedit /set {GUID} osdevice partition=D:
   ```

Now your boot menu should contain two entries for Windows 8 and Windows 7.

Comment: He wasn't asking how to boot windows 7, he wanted to know how to avoid using the Windows 8 boot loader, which takes a lot longer to load than the Windows 7 bootloader, plus requires a reboot to boot into 7 mode.